# Compare ground truth list of colours to another list of colours

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I have 2 arrays/lists of colours. One represents the *actual* dominant colours in an image, the other represents a list colours an algorithm thinks are the dominant colours in an image.

I want to compare the 2 lists to see how *close the algorithm was to the *actual* ground truth list of colours. *2 colours are considered close (the same) if the euclidean distance between them is <= 25.

The problem is that the 2 lists will not necessarily be the same length. And the colours in each list wont be in any order. The colours will always be in the colour space `CieLAB` (`cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB`).

Example of 2 lists I need to compare for similarity. Note they are in different order and different list lengths. But these 2 are considered the same because it found all the colours in the ground truth (plus some extra) and all those colours are <= 25 distance away.

> ground_truth = [[76, 177, 34], [36, 28, 237], [204, 72, 63], [0, 242, 255]]
>   results = [[35, 29, 234], [200, 72, 63], [70, 177, 34], [0, 242, 250], [45,29,67], [3,90,52]]

I have built a validator below but I'm not sure if its correct? Any advice on how to implement my objective above?

```
def validator(algoTuner, result, ground_truth):
    # Score = How close the colours in result are to the colours in ground_truth

    # p = pairwise distance between result and ground_truth
    # hits = get all distances from p that are <= max_dist
    # score = float(len(hits)) / len(ground_truth)
    dists = cdist(result, ground_truth, 'euclidean')
    score = float(len(dists[ dists < 25 ])) / len(ground_truth)
    return score
```

---

**Edit** after @Nakor's answer, would this be more correct? Remember the algorithm can find more colours than are in the ground truth. All that matters is the algorithm finds all the right colours in ground truth, any extra doesn't affect the score.

```
def validator(algoTuner, result, ground_truth, debug=False):
    dists = cdist(result, ground_truth, 'euclidean')
    correct_guesses = np.sum(dists<25, axis=1)
    correct_guesses = correct_guesses[ correct_guesses > 0 ]
    # score = correct_guesses.mean()
    score = float(correct_guesses.size) / len(ground_truth)

    if debug:
        print(len(correct_guesses))
        print(correct_guesses)
        print(score)
    return score
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the part where you calculate the score is not correct. Your counting the number of elements below 25 globally. But if I understood correctly, you're looking if, for each color in `ground_truth` there is at least one color in `result` that is less than 25 points away.

If this is the case, then I would modify your validator with:

```
def validator(algoTuner, result, ground_truth):
    # Score = How close the colours in result are to the colours in ground_truth

    # p = pairwise distance between result and ground_truth
    # hits = get all distances from p that are <= max_dist
    # score = float(len(hits)) / len(ground_truth)
    dists = cdist(result, ground_truth, 'euclidean')
    correct_guesses = np.sum(dists<25,axis=0)
    score = (correct_guesses>0).mean()
    return score
```

It returns the proportions of colors in ground_truth that are also present in result.
In your example, the score would be 1.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've edited my post, is that solution correct?

Comment: Actually there were 2 things that I corrected:
1) I did not know that you didn't care about extra colors in result. In this case, you just look at axis=0 (i.e. if for each colors in ground truth, you have a match)
2) I did not take into account that I could have several matches in correct guesses. So, when calculating the score, you need to do `score = (correct_guesses>0).mean()`